# What happens if you move into a point of interest not on your turn?

Tags: stuffed-fables

We encountered a story page where the story moves the stuffies when specific things happen. Doing so moved a stuffy whose turn it wasn't into a point of interest (POI).

Is there a specific rule to what happens that I am not reading? I did not see anything specific about this online.

We guessed it would be:

1. The POI activates for the stuffy whose turn it was
2. The POI activates for the stuffy who was on it
3. Nothing happens, but on the stuffy who was on it next turn (if still on it) it would activate (after white and black dice were assigned)
4. Nothing happens at all.

Option 2 seemed weird since a lot of the "event" stuff that happens require dice and out of turn stuffy would only possibly have a reserved die or conditional die.

Tried to keep this spoiler free but can add the scenario or more detail if needed.  It would also be nice to know if this happened for other general events (lost, vendors, objective tokens) if the ruling was the same.